# MongoDB replicaset on docker swarm

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, docker-swarm

I try to create a MongoDB replicaset in docker swarm services.
So far so good. The problem im facing is, when a container stops or is moved to a other docker host, the cluster breaks and i cant connect to it, because the container name has changed an no replication is possible.

I create a simple service, based on the MongoDB docs (https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/deploying-a-mongodb-cluster-with-docker) as follows:

```sh
docker service create --replicas=3 --network=paas --name=database mongo --replSet myReplicaSet --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

This runs on my 3 docker hosts (which are configured as a swarm) on each a docker container.

To create a replicaset out of it, i run on one docker host:

```sh
docker exec -it database.2.9qx7fuko225k8sojd0clx2r0e mongosh --eval "rs.initiate({
 _id: \"myReplicaSet\",
 members: [
   {_id: 0, host: \"database.2.9qx7fuko225k8sojd0clx2r0e\"},
   {_id: 1, host: \"database.3.7bd9fotnkroq00c0n6rgyjm36\"},
   {_id: 2, host: \"database.1.vb17p0vpp6kgw4bpbat1a9sbh\"}
 ]
})"
```

The names used as "host", have i from each docker host with `docker container ls`. Output:

```
[root@n1 ~]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS       NAMES
f83f4fe69e87   mongo:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 seconds ago   Up 20 seconds   27017/tcp   database.2.9qx7fuko225k8sojd0clx2r0e
```

```
[root@n2 ~]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS       NAMES
99694587656b   mongo:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 seconds ago   Up 13 seconds   27017/tcp   database.3.7bd9fotnkroq00c0n6rgyjm36
```

```
[root@n3 ~]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS       NAMES
f83f4fe69e87   mongo:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   38 seconds ago   Up 33 seconds   27017/tcp   database.1.vb17p0vpp6kgw4bpbat1a9sbh
```

Till this point everything works fine and i can do whatever i want with the MongoDB cluster.

Now when i reboot a docker member, or stop a mongodb container on purpose to test things, as soon as all 3 Database container have restarted, the cluster is broken.

Reason for that, the container do not have the same name when (re-)started on a other docker host. The last part in the name changes, which breaks my cluster configuration.

E.g.: `database.n.<whatever>`, this `<whatever>` changes every time something happens to the container (restart/moved/crashed).

How can i fix this issue and deploy a MongoDB cluster on docker swarm?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct solution to your problem, docker swarm services' containers can't have static hostnames set (as opposed to ones created 'manually' by docker compose within the docker engine). But, there's a workaround:

Instead of defining one single swarm, service with your `replicas=3`, define three individual services (perhaps within a stack), each with `replicas=1`, and assemble your mongo replicaset based on the service names, not the individual container names.

Note that if you have multiple nodes in your swarm and are running local volumes, you'll also need to make sure each replica always runs on the same physical node. You can do this by assigning each node a unique label (e.g. `docker node update --label-add mongo_replica=replica01 nodename`), and then then adding a placement constraint based on that (e.g. `--constraint 'node.labels.mongo_replica == replica01'`, pay attention to the double-equal here!).

The downside of this method is, as the number of replicas grow, scaling requires creating a whole new additional service per replica, instead of simply `docker service scale mongodb=4` or similar.